# How to publish a python package which has external https request in it?

Tags: python, publish

I've written a python package to do some analytics work, the code fetches data with https from an API hosted on my own AWS. The API requires an authorization token or username/password.

Now I want to publish this python package to PYPI, how should I deal with this authorization thing to make other people can use this package?

Comment: Remove authentication from the API or allow the user of your package to provide their own authentication details that could then access the resource?

Comment: If it's a small amount of data - consider it publishing somewhere publicly (github?) - then allowing people to access it without credentials. Definitely do not publish your credentials or make any workaround. Maybe you can include whole dataset with that package.

Comment: Hi @avloss, The data is private and I only want users who is authorized can access it.

Comment: Hi @IainShelvington, if the users provide their own authentication, anyone can access the API. I only want users with right can use the data.